# Proper way to update the parent key in a child table for multiple rows after an update in the parent

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have 2 tables that essentially have a parent-child relationship. So the child table has a column that references the primary key of the parent table.

In a nutshell the parent table is like an aggregation of the child table where each row of the parent contains a sum of the data of a group of rows in the child table and in the child table each row in this group refers to the "summed/total" row in the parent table.
Now I am not sure how to model this correctly.

I mean I insert rows in the child table letting the column for the parent key be `NULL` (step 1).

Then when it is time to add/sum the rows, I insert a new record in the parent table (step 2) with the total of the groups that I happen to collect.

Now the problem I have (step 3) is how to update the child rows with the parent id that was created by the just inserted row?

At this point I also do not know the ids of the rows I summed.

Should I be selecting the ids of the rows and then do an update on this rows to replace the `NULL` with the new parent id?  Should this be inside a transaction?

Am I doing this wrong? Should these steps happen automatically somehow due to constraints?

Comment: Can you give us more informations? Datas, tables for example?

Comment: @T0to:Really simple. 2 tables one references the other. Table A has column `amount` and table B has column `total_amount`. Groups of rows in table A are summed over `amount` and populated in the `total_amount` in table B

Answer (score 0):

Your steps should be

```
1. Insert into parent table and get the parent id (Guessing auto increment) in a variable. 
    At this time, your sum field would be 0/null. (This calculation should have happened prior to insert ideally.)
2. Insert into child table along with the parent id. 
3. Get the sum of all fields (Based on your requirement) based on the parentID
4. Update back the parent table with the patientID.
```

Is this you are looking for? Do I miss anything obvious?

Comment: The problem is that the rows are inserted in advance in the child table. So the rows already exist with the parent id as NULL. Then when I insert the row with the sum in the parent table, I need to replace this NULL with the parent id. So it is not the steps you are actually mentioning

Comment: I just mentioned the standard way to handle this problem . The solution is inside your question itself. Parent should be inserted before child. Incase you are not at all able to do that , due to any reason, then you need to generate a GUID and use it as a temporary id in your child and parent table just for mapping

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a big design thing, It depends at which prospective you are seeking answers.

first, The design should clearly state that integrity should be maintained between the parent

and child table.

See the below example,

If below is Child table at any particular time.

ID  Value
1   3

1   1

1   3

2   3

2   5

2   1

3   2

3   6

3   4

The Parent Table should look like

ID  Value
1   7

2   9

3   12

You Should Clearly mention , what should happen if a row is deleted/Updated from Child or Same with Parent.

Now

From Development point of view you need triggers.

Suppose a new Id is inserted in child then a record must be inserted at the same time in parent table.

Similarly updates and deleted need to be propagated to parent and Delete of parent need to be propagated to child.

Please let me know in case of any other query.

Comment: `Suppose a new Id is inserted in child then a record must be inserted at the same time in parent table.` Not really since it is only agreggations